# How can I get “live” output from a Docker container in Go?

Tags: docker, stdout

How would I go about using the Golang Docker SDK to build service that has live container output? This does not seem to be possible other than when the process has finished.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe [Get Container Logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.35/#operation/ContainerLogs)? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will try get container logs, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker logs --follow` command will continue streaming the new output.

Comment: Thanks for the help.